# What is the right way to assign element of an array to state using React hooks?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making simple weather app based on api

In the beggining of functional component I declare this

```
   const [pressure, setPressure] = useState("")
   const [hourTemp, setHourTemp] = useState([])
```

Then I download data object from api using fetch() and assign values to state.
Pressure(for example) is a single value, but in my app I need hourly forecast so I take whole hourly array and filter it (it has 48 hours and I only need 10).

```
    setPressure(data.current.pressure)
    let newArray = data.hourly.filter(a => {
       return data.hourly.indexOf(a) < 10
    })
```

After newArray is created  I can console.log [image] it and it prints array of 10 objects exactly how I want it.

But when I assign this array to state

```
setHourTemp(newArray)
```

and then pass an element as props, it returns undefined

```
 <WeatherBlock temp={hourTemp[0].temp}/> //TypeError: hourTemp[0] is undefined
```

Comment: Are you checking if hourTemp is empty or null before rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `fetch` which is an async function, it need time to load the data. When the first time you call / render `hourTemp[0]`, the data still empty, and it returns error undefined. So you need to validate if the data is exist or not. There are many ways to do this:

1. Using ternary expression

```
<WeatherBlock temp={hourTemp[0] ? hourTemp[0].temp : 0}/>
```

2. Using conditional rendering, you use if else before the return

```
    if(hourTemp[0]){
      return <WeatherBlock temp={hourTemp[0].temp}/> 
    } else {
      return <WeatherBlock temp={0}/> 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a empty/null validation to check if your array is valid.

There are many ways to do that, but to test:

```
{hourTemp ? <WeatherBlock temp={hourTemp[0].temp}/> : <></> }
```